# Is the Cayley graph of a free group dense on the Poincare disc?

Tags: free-groups, cayley-graphs

In other words, every point inside the disc corresponds to a word (possibly of infinite length) of the free group;  Is that correct?

With this embedding:

[image]

Comment: With respect to what embedding of the Cayley graph in the disc?

Comment: (I don't know how to call it, but see the edited question)

Comment: No. I do not think so.

Comment: Looks like it's not true... the set of points is of fractal dimension less than 2, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Not true. The free group on two (or finitely many) generators has countably many elements, the hyperbolic disc has uncountably many.

If you consider also the edges of the Cayley graph it is still not true. Look at the circle around the center of the hyperbolic disc which intersects the Cayley graph in the four points $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$. The interior of this circle is not reached again, as all edges point outward. Hence the only points from the Cayley graph contained in this circle lie on the four main edges adjacent to the center (neutral element of the free group) that you already see in your drawing.

Comment: The OP first asks if the embedding is 'dense'... What if he rewords his question to ask if every word in the group has a corresponding point on the disc, would that be reasonable. Further, might it be possible to show that every open neighborhood in the disc contains one of these corresponding points?

Comment: Every word in the (finitely generated) free group has a corresponding point in the disc. Here we are talking about the vertices of the Cayley graph and by the way this graph is drawn this fact is obvious. The other reformulation again does not hold. See my answer above. Take an open neighborhood inside the gaps (white space) between Cayley graph edges for this.